# How to programmatically install the latest epel-release rpm, without knowing its version number?

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

My first post here, but I googled around and cannot find a simple way to do this.

I have a program which automatically configures new CentOS Linux servers as they come online.  As part of the process it installs the latest version of epel-release rpm.

The command I use looks like this:

```
$ rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm && \
     yum clean all
```

This works great... until they change the rpm file to epel-release-6-8.noarch, then epel-release-6-9.noarch, and so on.  They seem to update the version every 3-4 months.  This is a problem, because if the repository updates the epel-release version number, my scripts will fail because it has no idea what that version should be.

I failed to find a link that might redirect to the latest epel rpm file, so I have no choice but to hard-code the version into my install scripts, and change it when they fail.

Anyone know a simple (non-hard-coded) way to download the latest epel rpm without knowing the version number?  I'm hoping for a way that does not involve dong a curl on the repo file list and grep'ing the url, but curious what anyone might suggest?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following script will do the trick:

```
cat <<EOM >/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-bootstrap.repo
[epel]
name=Bootstrap EPEL
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-\$releasever&arch=\$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
EOM

yum --enablerepo=epel -y install epel-release
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-bootstrap.repo
```

It should work on RHEL/CentOS 5 and 6. I didn't test version 4.

Comment: This is a great idea!  I adapted it for an Ansible playbook to break dependencies on a few hard-coded repo RPM URLs: https://github.com/zigg/octothorpe/commit/c3b0cdf751a6818385925c7b358361e000076daf

Comment: **NOTE for CentOS users**
You can install EPEL by running yum install epel-release. The package is included in the CentOS Extras repository, enabled by default. Source: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: Does not work in `RHEL7`, because there's no `repo=epel-7Server`. We need `$releasever` without the word "Server"

Answer (score 4):

The [EPEL project](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has recently implemented "latest" symlinks for the epel-release package.

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
​https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

See https://fedorahosted.org/epel/ticket/8#comment:12

Answer (score 0):

Do it right from the shell:

```
$ EPEL_BASEURL=http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$(awk '/rhel/ {print $2}' /etc/rpm/macros.dist)/$(uname -p)/
$ rpm -ivh $EPEL_BASEURL$(curl -s $EPEL_BASEURL | grep epel-release | awk -F'<|>' '{print $5}')
Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.zRXE1U: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:epel-release           ########################################### [100%]
```

I've tested this on CentOS 6.4, 6.5 and 6.6 and RHEL 6.5 and 6.6, but the contents of /etc/rpm/macros.dist and the HTML code from http://dl.fedoraproject.org should be consistent on all platforms, so this should work on all platforms.

For posterity's sake, here it is with more detail:

```
$ EPEL_BASEURL=http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$(awk '/rhel/ {print $2}' /etc/rpm/macros.dist)/$(uname -p)/
# http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/
$ EPEL_RELEASE_RPM=$(curl -s $EPEL_BASEURL | grep epel-release | awk -F'<|>' '{print $5}')
# epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
$ EPEL_RELEASE_RPMURL=$EPEL_BASEURL$EPEL_RELEASE_RPM
# http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
$ rpm -ivh $EPEL_RELEASE_RPMURL
Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ep6xy3: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:epel-release           ########################################### [100%]
```